# google-map-react centering the map with multiple markers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-map-react

How do I find the center of the map when I have more than 2 markers? When I have only 2 I've done it like this:

```
midPoint(trackingLocation, deliveryLocation) {
    if (deliveryLocation) {
      return [
        trackingLocation.lat + (deliveryLocation.lat - trackingLocation.lat) * 0.5,
        trackingLocation.lng + (deliveryLocation.lng - trackingLocation.lng) * 0.5
      ];
    } else {
      return trackingLocation;
    }
  }
```

But how do I calculate the center when I have 5 markers?

Thank you

Comment: do  you have a github repo for this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the rectangle that contains all the markers, then use the midpoint of that rectangle.

First, go through all the markers and find:

- minLat
- minLng
- maxLat
- maxLng

Then you can do the same calculation you did for two markers with these two points:

- (minLat, minLng)
- (maxLat, maxLng)